# Make properties case insensitive

Tags: c#, .net, utf8json

EDIT: I am using [Utf8Json](https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json) not [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-6.0)

Is there any possible way to make Utf8Json Deserializer case insensitive? Currently if json key-case doesn't match property-case then values are not populated.

I don't want to use `[DataMember(Name ="...")]`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"testprop\":123,\"name\":\"TestObject\"}";
        var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Temp>(json);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Temp
{
    public int TestProp { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-casing) help?

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang I have edited the post. I am not using System.Text.Json.

Comment: Sorry, my fault that I missed that.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to pass in a [`JsonSerializerOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=net-6.0) object with the [`PropertyNameCaseInsensitive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.propertynamecaseinsensitive?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions-propertynamecaseinsensitive) property set to true. For example:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};

var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Temp>(json, options);
```

Comment: isn't JsonSerializerOptions for System.Text.Json?

If I use this then I will have to use the Deserializer from System.Text.Json instead of Utf8Json.

Comment: As sorry, I missed that. So as far as I can tell there isn't an easy way to do it with Utf8Json. You might be able to make your own formatted `IJsonFormatter` if you copy how the internal ones work. There's one in there for camel case that you could copy, but it would require a tonne of copying out internal code that hasn't been exposed as public for some reason. Is there a reason you don't want to use System.Text.Json? Utf8Json hasn't really been changed for 2 years now so I don't think there's many reasons to stick with it.

Comment: Project requirement, and Utf8Json is 4x faster compared to System.Text.Json

Comment: It used to be 4x faster but that isn't the case any more. Especially since STJ added source generators. It wouldn't surprise me if STJ is actually faster now.